# disqus return 0 Comments

Tags: javascript, comments, disqus

I have Place the following code before site's closing `</body>` tag:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'MY_SHORT_NAME'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function () {
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
    }());
    </script>
```

I did Append `#disqus_thread` to the href attribute in links.

```
<a href="http://foo.com/bar.html#disqus_thread">Link</a>.
```

and I try to add some comments to article but still returning 0 comments.

As you can see in Side "A" this is the front page where it should show the number of comments.

In Side "B" it's inside the article as you can see there is 2 comments but on the front page Side "A" it shows 0 comments.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem. After changing url of the page comments counter start working correct. NOTICE: **if you change url you will lost your comments**

PS: make sure that you clear your cache =)